# Angular 5 - Validating own input components derived from a base componet

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Currently we are going to port our old application to new technologies and get rid of old design failures and improve the overall UX.

At the moment we are wrapping all standard inputs in own components, so we can change them very easily if needed. All our input components could have a validation but the input components can be nested in an input group of bootstrap, like this:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <div>
    <label>Birth Year</label>
    <vng-controls-textbox #user="ngModel" name="user" minlength="5" ngModel ></vng-controls-textbox>

    <label>Text</label>
    <vng-controls-textbox #text="ngModel" name="text" maxlength="5" ngModel ></vng-controls-textbox>
  </div>

   <div vng-control-group [icon]="['fa','user']">
        <vng-controls-textbox required type="text" #username="ngModel" ngModel name="Username">
        </vng-controls-textbox>
        <vng-controls-textbox required type="password" #password="ngModel" ngModel name="Passwort">
        </vng-controls-textbox>
   </div>
</form>
```

The validation works fine for standalone input components, but we want to deactivate the validation for each nested component in our  and get all errors of all possible controls with validations. The desired solution should be a generic approach and no specifics, if possible.

Our base component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Input, Output, forwardRef, AfterViewInit, Self } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-base' 
})
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, Validator, AfterViewInit//, IControlBase<any>
{
    public ngControl: any;
    private parseError: boolean;
    private _value: any = '';

    /** Input value */
    @Input() set value(newValue: any) {
        if (newValue != this._value && newValue !== undefined) {
            console.log("[BaseComponent]: Set value " + newValue);
            this.valueChange.emit(newValue);
            this._value = newValue;
        }

    };
    get value(): any {
        if (this._value) {
            return this._value;
        }
    }
    /** Platzhalter */
    @Input() placeholder: any;

    /** Disabled */
    @Input() disabled: boolean;

    /** Name des Controls */
    @Input() name: string;

    /** Optional: Typ des Controls (Text, Password) */
    @Input() type?: string;

    @Input() hideErrors: boolean = false;

    @Output() valueChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    // this is the initial value set to the component
    public writeValue(obj: any) {
        if (obj !== undefined && obj) {
            console.log("[BaseComponent] writeValue ", obj)
            this._value = obj;
        }
    }

    // registers 'fn' that will be fired wheb changes are made
    // this is how we emit the changes back to the form
    public registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.propagateChange = fn;
    }

    // validates the form, returns null when valid else the validation object
    // in this case we're checking if the json parsing has passed or failed from the onChange method
    public validate(c: FormControl) {

        return null;
    }

    // not used, used for touch input
    public registerOnTouched() { }

    // change events from the textarea
    private onChange(event) {

        if (event.target.value !== undefined) {
            console.log("[BaseComponent] "+this.name+" OnChange " + event.target.value)
            // get value from text area
            this._value = event.target.value;
            this.propagateChange(this._value);
        }

    }

    // the method set in registerOnChange to emit changes back to the form
    private propagateChange = (_: any) => { };

    registerOnValidatorChange?(fn: () => void): void {
        console.log("[BaseComponent]: registerOnValidatorChange");
    }
    setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        console.log("[BaseComponent]: setDisabledState");
    }

    constructor(@Self() ngControl: NgControl) {
        ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
        if (ngControl) {
            this.ngControl = ngControl;
        }
    }
    ngOnInit() {

    }
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        //debugger;
        //this.placeholder = this.translateService.instant((this.placeholder ? this.placeholder : this.name))
    }

}
```

Our control group component typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Host, Self } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer, FormControl, AbstractControl, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { BaseComponent } from '../../_bases/base.component'
import { QueryList, ViewChildren, ContentChildren, TemplateRef, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';

import { TextboxComponent } from '../textbox/textbox.component';

/**
 * Komponente für Input-Groups
 * @example
 *  <div vng-control-group [config]="textboxUsernameConfig">
 *      // Kann ein diverses Control sein, was als CSS-Klasse "form-control besitzt"
 *      <input class="input form-control" />
 *  </div>
 *
 *  // oder
 *
 *  <div vng-control-group [icon]="['fa','user']" [label]="Test Label" [position]="'append'">
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'div[vng-control-group]',
  templateUrl: './control-group.component.html'
})

export class ControlGroupComponent {
    private controlContainer: ControlContainer;
    public formControl: AbstractControl;

    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef<any>;

    ngAfterContentInit() {

    } 

    /** Konfiguration der Inputgroup als Objekt */
    @Input() config: InputGroupConfig;

    /** Icon als Attribut (z.B. im HTML) */
    @Input() icon?: object;

    /** Label als Attribut (z.B. im HTML) */
    @Input() label?: string;

    /** Position als Attribut (z.B. im HTML) */
    @Input() position?: GroupPosition;

    constructor(@Host() parent: ControlContainer) {
        //this.controlContainer = parent;
        //this.formControl = this.controlContainer.control;
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        // Wenn kein Konfig-Objekt übergeben worden ist, setze die Attribute bzw. setze Default-Werte
        if (!this.config) {
            console.log("[ControlGroupComponent]: Keine Config übergeben")
            this.config = {
                icon: this.icon || ['fa', 'question'],
                label: this.label || '',
                position: this.position || GroupPosition.prepend
            }
        }
    }
}


export interface InputGroupConfig {
    icon?: object,
    label?: string,
    position?: GroupPosition
}

export enum GroupPosition {
    append = 'append',
    prepend = 'prepend'
}
```

Our control-group html:

```
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
      </div>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>

Show error component (ts/html):
// show-errors.component.ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControlDirective, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
 selector: 'show-errors',
 template: `
   <ul *ngIf="shouldShowErrors()">
     <li style="color: red" *ngFor="let error of listOfErrors()">{{error}}</li>
   </ul>
 `,
})
export class ShowErrorsComponent {

 private static readonly errorMessages = {
   'required': () => 'This field is required',
   'minlength': (params) => 'The min number of characters is ' + params.requiredLength,
   'maxlength': (params) => 'The max allowed number of characters is ' + params.requiredLength,
   'pattern': (params) => 'The required pattern is: ' + params.requiredPattern,
   'years': (params) => params.message,
   'countryCity': (params) => params.message,
   'uniqueName': (params) => params.message,
   'telephoneNumbers': (params) => params.message,
   'telephoneNumber': (params) => params.message
 };

 @Input()
 private control: AbstractControlDirective | AbstractControl;

 shouldShowErrors(): boolean {
   return this.control &&
     this.control.errors &&
     (this.control.dirty || this.control.touched);
 }

 listOfErrors(): string[] {
   return Object.keys(this.control.errors)
     .map(field => this.getMessage(field, this.control.errors[field]));
 }

 private getMessage(type: string, params: any) {
   return ShowErrorsComponent.errorMessages[type](params);
 }

}
```

How can we achieve that? I'm pretty stuck since 3 days and can't get it working.I really don't know how to disable the error messages in the content of  and print all errors messages of all nested inputs under the input group.

Besides that, our nested inputs within the control group are looking pretty bad:

[Bad bootstrap format on nested inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU78y.png)

I've created a stackblitz example which demonstrates the behavior of both problems:
https://angular-ng-bootstrap-khjkkhhjkhk.stackblitz.io

Editor:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-khjkkhhjkhk

Do you have any idea how can we fix that too? I guess it's because of the  which wraps the controls in an additional div which causes the strange looking inputs. Preferably we want to style them in the manner of bootstrap.

Comment: Nobody got a clue? :-(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the case but I see you're not declaring the providers in @Component decorator using ControlValueAccessor.

Like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-input',
    templateUrl: './input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputComponent), multi: true },
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputComponent), multi: true }
    ]
})
```